# how to save bulk of files in python

Tags: python, nltk

I would like to fix some textual errors in txt files using regular expression in python.
The total number of txt files is 487.

It seems like loading all files was successful. Yet still have no idea **how to save** the reviewed new file (after adjusting regular expression process) in separated txt files.

additional code is attached below.

```
import nltk
import shutil
import re
from nltk.corpus import*
corpus_root = "C:/Users/82106/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data/corpora/cess_esp/Genomics-Informatics-Corpus-master/raw_text2/"
giCorpus=PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*\.txt', encoding='utf-8')
giCorpus.fileids()
len(giCorpus.fileids())

for file in giCorpus.fileids():
    giRaw=giCorpus.raw(file)

    pattern = re.findall(r'[a-z]+-\n[a-z]+', giRaw)
    len(pattern)
    match =re.findall(r'[\r\n]{2,}', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'[\r\n]{2,}',' ', giRaw)
    match =re.findall(r'3 1 UTR', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'3 1 UTR','3\'UTR', giRaw)
    match =re.findall(r'www.sanger . ', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'www.sanger . ',r'www.sanger.', giRaw)
    match =re.findall(r'/tfcraRAM', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'/tfcraRAM', 'MicroRNA', giRaw)
    match =re.findall(r'miRNA[a-z]+.', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'miRNA[a-z]+.', r'miRNA:human ', giRaw)
    
    print(giRaw)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but hopefully this should work.

```
import nltk
import shutil
import re
from nltk.corpus import*
corpus_root = "C:/Users/82106/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data/corpora/cess_esp/Genomics-Informatics-Corpus-master/raw_text2/"
giCorpus=PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*\.txt', encoding='utf-8')
giCorpus.fileids()
len(giCorpus.fileids())

for file in giCorpus.fileids():
    new_file_nm = "modified_{file_name}".format(file_name=file)
    giRaw=giCorpus.raw(file)

    pattern = re.findall(r'[a-z]+-\n[a-z]+', giRaw)
    len(pattern)
    match =re.findall(r'[\r\n]{2,}', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'[\r\n]{2,}',' ', giRaw)
    match =re.findall(r'3 1 UTR', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'3 1 UTR','3\'UTR', giRaw)
    match =re.findall(r'www.sanger . ', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'www.sanger . ',r'www.sanger.', giRaw)
    match =re.findall(r'/tfcraRAM', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'/tfcraRAM', 'MicroRNA', giRaw)
    match =re.findall(r'miRNA[a-z]+.', giRaw)

    re.sub(r'miRNA[a-z]+.', r'miRNA:human ', giRaw)
    
    print(giRaw)
    
    with open(new_file_nm, "w") as f1:
        f1.write(giRow)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insight! But sadly, I got an error saying UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-f564ea395648> in <module>
     24 
     25     with open(new_file_nm, "w") as f1:
---> 26         f1.write(giRaw)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character '\xab' in position 15831: illegal multibyte sequence

Comment: ```giRow.encode('latin-1')``` will encode to latin-1. You may choose encoding as you may need. Hope this helps